# Why does the sky texture look normal in the Viewport Display, but when I render the picture it turns into this?

Tags: rendering, texturing

In the Viewport Display, the sky looks fine, but when I render it, for some reason, it just turns into an orange mess. This happens in both cycles and eevee.

[image: Sky in Viewport Display]
[image: Sky after rendering]

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have an object hidding your scene? Check the Outliner

Comment: hard to tell without the bland file